# Why does jQuery compress whitespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX call that returns a table.  Here's a row from that table:

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Excelsior</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>Erika D. Kirby (SR)<br/>Ariana M. Johnson (JR)<br/>Maddison Z. Lacey (SO)<br/>Jada F. Holm (SR)</td>
    <td>1:53.45</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>8.00</td>
</tr>
```

I use jQuery to write that table into an existing div element:

```
function display_scores( args , response ) {
    $("#results").html( response );
}
```

Here, `repsonse` contains the table in question.  When it's rendered, the whitespace between parts of names is gone.  This is what I get from the fourth cell:

```
<td>ErikaD.Kirby(SR)<br>ArianaM.Johnson(JR)<br>MaddisonZ.Lacey(SO)<br>JadaF.Holm(SR)</td>
```

What happened to my whitespace?

Comment: jQuery won't do that. Have you checked the response still has spaces?

Comment: I agree with @RoryMcCrossan.  Not jQuery at fault here.

Comment: Maybe it's because you're missing `<table></table>` around your table? It's invalid to put a tr directly inside a div.

Comment: You must be doing some sort of `.replace(/\s/g, '')` regex to remove all whitespace, check to see if something like that is in there.

Comment: Are you displaying it inside of a pre tag? otherwise, the browser will consolidate the spaces.

Comment: How are viewing this rendered content? Mostly that would have optimized. And how does it really matters?

Comment: mcpDESIGNS wins the brass ring.  I had this in my AJAX wrapper and had forgotten all about it.

    clean_response = clean_response.replace(/\s/gm, '');